# Type circular reference issue graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have two resources: `Purchase` and `Category` where purchase belongs to a category and category has many purchases. I'm trying to allow querying such as:

```
query {
    purchases {
        description,
        amount,
        category {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
query {
    categories {
        name,
        purchases {
            description,
            amount
        }
    }
}
```

When setting up my types, I get the following error:

```
Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Category".
```

I'm pretty sure this is a circular reference problem, but I've used thunks as I've seen other answers suggest:

```
// Category/type.js
const {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLInt, GraphQLString, GraphQLList} = require('graphql/type');
const {purchaseType} = require('../Purchase');

const categoryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Category',
    description: 'a purchasing category',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: GraphQLInt
        },
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        purchases: {
            type: new GraphQLList(purchaseType),
            resolve (category) {
                return category.getPurchases();
            }
        }
    })
});

module.exports = categoryType; 

// Category/index.js
const categoryType = require('./type');
const categoryQuery = require('./query');

module.exports = {
    categoryType,
    categoryQuery
};

// Purchase/type.js
const {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLInt, GraphQLString, GraphQLFloat} = require('graphql/type');
const {categoryType} = require('../Category');

const purchaseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Purchase',
    description: 'a specific purchase',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
        },
        description: {
            type: GraphQLString,
        },
        amount: {
            type: GraphQLFloat,
        },
        category: {
            type: categoryType,
            resolve (purchase) {
                return purchase.getCategory();
            }
        }
    })
});

module.exports = purchaseType;

// Purchase/index.js
const purchaseType = require('./type');
const purchaseQuery = require('./query');

module.exports = {
    purchaseType,
    purchaseQuery
};
```

Did I mess something up here or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

**Edit #1**
What leads me to believe this is a circular reference problem, is if I change the field `category` on the `purchaseType` to the following:

```
category: {
        // type: categoryType,
        // resolve (purchase) {
        //     return purchase.getCategory();
        // }
        type: GraphQLInt,
        resolve (purchase) {
            return 10;
        }
    }
```

and do something similar to the `categoryType` `purchases` field, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

`Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Category".`

This error is clear which means that the various `GraphQLObjectType` you have declared contains the name `Category` multiple times, please check your all the names of `GraphQLObjectType`, and change it, shouldn't be same or please update your all `Type` in the Question.

*NOTE:* all the names of `GraphQLType` must be unique, it shouldn't match eachother

```
const categoryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Category', -------> others GraphQLObjectType may have same name Category
    description: 'a purchasing category',
    fields: () => ({
         .....
    })
});
```

Comment: I have checked all my types and I only have `category` once. I updated my question with something I tried.

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being a capitalization problem.

In my `schema.js` I was doing:

```
const {purchaseType, purchaseQuery} = require('./resources/purchase/');
```

In `Category/type.js` I was doing:

```
const {purchaseType} = require('../Purchase');
```

Node caches modules in a case-sensitive manner, so it was loading the `purchaseTyp` module twice.